# Cannot infer type arguments for ArrayAdapter<> in Android

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SeekBar seekBar=findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.setMax(20);
    seekBar.setProgress(10);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            final ArrayList<String> tables = new ArrayList<>();
            final ArrayAdapter<String> adaptor = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tables);
```

> ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tables)
>   ;

This line is giving error of cannot infer type argument.
Any suggestions ?

I am trying to add data to ArrayList and then that to ListView.

Comment: The "this" pass in the ArrayAdapter currently reference to seekbar, which is not the valid context. You have to pass YourActivityName.this in activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use YourActivityName.this instead of this.

```
 final ArrayAdapter<String> adaptor = new ArrayAdapter<String>(YourActivityName.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tables);
```

Let me know if still does not work.